# How to write a recipe to install oh-my-zsh using its install.sh in chef?

Tags: vagrant, chef-recipe

I am trying to build a recipe that basically does 2 things:

1. Install zsh
2. Install oh-my-zsh

Currentltly I am doing the follwoing to install them in my finsal.sh file. # Added zsh shell.

```
# Install ZSH
sudo apt-get install zsh
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | sudo ZSH=/home/vagrant/.oh-my-zsh sh  
export ZSH=/home/vagrant/.oh-my-zsh
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh vagrant
zsh

# Change the oh my zsh default theme.
cp /home/vagrant/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template /home/vagrant/.zshrc
chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.zshrc
chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.oh-my-zsh
```

I looked for existing cookbooks and found a few. However, they all seem to be more that what I need. For example, I found this one https://github.com/shingara/oh-my-zsh-chef but it has dependencies that I don't need.

The questions is how do I replace the above bash script with a chef recipe?

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there?

Comment: I want to replace what I did in a bash script with a chef recipe.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/shingara/oh-my-zsh-chef has ONE dependency, git.  If that's too much for you, I'd suggest you fork the cookbook and strip out the git dependency.  In either case, that cookbook provides a pretty good starting point for you.  If you have specific questions regarding how to modify it, let us, know.

Comment: Thanks, this may just work for me. The thing is that chef complains about the git cookbook does not exist while it does exist. It is installed in a custom recipe. In addition, how do I override the attributes as explained in the readme? Do I override the recipe itself or in the the json configuration?

Comment: You need to make sure the git `cookbook` is on your chef server.  As for attributes, you can override them in your own recipe, the role, environment, or node, or in the json passed to the chef-client command.  Any of the above will work.